# Trying to have a bot that adds role to someone in a server if they send a certain thing to the bot in DMS discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want a bot that gives users a certain role in my server if they send a certain phrase to the bot in DMs.

This is what I have so far:

```
if message.guild is None:
  if passphrase in message.content:
    await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")

    serv = client.get_guild(00000000000000000000)
    role = serv.get_role(000000000000000000000)
    if message.author in serv.members:
      message.author.add_roles(role, reason="Member was verified via DMs.")
      await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")
```

If the passphrase is in the message, the user gets "You've been verified!" in their DM but the user doesn't get the role specified in the server.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's a coroutine, not just a normal function, you need to await it.

Comment: Just tried this, did not work :/

Comment: Why? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors appear, and the last line of code runs.

Comment: Are you sure you put the await in the correct place? `await message.author.add_roles(...)`

Comment: ```
await message.author.add_roles(role, reason="Member was verified via DMs.")
```

Comment: ^^ This is what it looks like

Answer (score -1):

1. `message.author` is a [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) object. Is has not `add_roles` method you need to get it as a guild member using `serv.get_member(message.author.id)`.
2. `add_roles` is a coroutine therefore you need to await it using `await` keyword

Your code should looks like this:

```py
if message.guild is None:
    if passphrase in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")
        serv = client.get_guild(00000000000000000000)
        role = serv.get_role(000000000000000000000)
        member = serv.get_member(message.author.id)
        if member us not None
            await member.add_roles(role, reason="Member was verified via DMs.")
            await message.channel.send("You've been verified!")
```

Comment: First, I'm not sure what the "member us not None" syntax does?  Second, I tried calling add_roles() on the member object, but it still does not add the roles in the target server.

Comment: Where did you take from that `message.author` *always* returns a `discord.User` instance? It can return either a `discord.User` or `discord.Member` instance depending where the message was sent (DM or guild)

Comment: –@ŁukaszKwieciński Yes, it can returns also `discord.Member` but not in this context when we check `if message.guild is None:`.